# В чем преимущество em от px для отступов?

Tags: css

В чем именно разница для отступов и для радиуса?

Даже при изменении масштаба отступы всегда одинаковые

```css
.px, .px * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.em, .em * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.6em;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="px"><div><div>PX</div></div></div>
<div class="em"><div><div>EM</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Добавьте к стилям, например, `div { font-size: 2em }`  и сразу поймёте разницу и преимущества

Comment: @Alexey то есть разница будет только если присутствует `font-size` ?

Comment: Часто удобно установить размеры отступов, радиусов, теней и т.п. относительно размера шрифта элемента, чтобы они менялись пропорционально, вместе со шрифтом. Информация про единицы измерения в CSS вот тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: @Alexey, Спасибо, почти все понял. Получается 1em это всегда 16px от шрифта из настроек браеузера

Comment: `1em` соответствует текущему размеру шрифта родительского элемента. Эта единица может быть равна любому количеству пикселей. А вот `1rem` — размер шрифта корневого элемента (:root; <html>) как раз обычно равен 16px, если не установить иное значение.